# How to get full screen background with a transparent statusbar?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to show a react-native-maps in full screen. But the header of the StackNavigator (react native navigation) should be shown over the map. The status bar too. I want to add a small gradient over the map to make the status bar and back button (and maybe more buttons on the right header side) more readable.

At the moment the use of the StackNavigator automatically limiting the "fullscreen" map (flex: 1) to the bottom of the navigation header.

How to solve this?

react-native: 0.46

react-navigation: 1.0.0-beta.11

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the map to be full screen but tab and stack navigators to be above it. I don't think this is possible without removing the screen from all navigators, and implement transparent views above your map.

Comment: Yes! You are right.. I hope there is another way...

Answer (score 3):

Just Use React-Native StatusBar API

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor={Color.TRANSPARENT} translucent={true} />
    <MapView
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
      style={styles.map}
      region={{
        latitude: 37.78825,
        longitude: -122.4324,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
      }}
    />
  </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to solve this, just add the following to your screen-component:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    headerBackTitleStyle: {
        opacity: 0,
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff'
};
```

And add some LinearGradients (if you want) and you have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Would be better if you include what versions you are currently using, for future documentation.